# Reformatting a name to lastname,firstname

Tags: javascript

I need your help here as I am not quite sure what I am doing here. How would I go about programmatically reformatting a name to lastname, firstname. I am going to also throw in some curve balls here:

```
Ex.1 John Michael Smith
Smith, John Michael

Ex.2 Richard P. Johnson
Johnson, Richard P.

Ex.3 Jane Doe
Doe, Jane
```

Comment: Posted comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. This function consider the last word of string as `lastname` and the others as `firstname`.

```js
function reformatter(str) {
  var output = "",
    arr = str.split(' ');
  output += arr[arr.length - 1] + ', ';
  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i ++) {
    output += arr[i];
    if(i < arr.length - 2) {
      output += " ";
    }
  }
  return output;
}

var x = "John Michael Smith";
console.log(reformatter(x));

var y = "Richard P. Johnson"
console.log(reformatter(y));

var z = "Jane Doe";
console.log(reformatter(z));
```

Comment: A very user friendly solution! Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest find the last occurance of a space `' '` character, split the string at that point. You would have the part up to that space as `firstName`, and the part after that space as `lastName`.  Then you can concatenate them as you wish, for instance: `newName = lastName + ', ' + firstName;`

See the reference material at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String